# cancel mapbox mapview animation programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

Is it possible to programmatically cancel a mapbox mapView animation, managed by a method such as setCamera(), the same way this animation is canceled when the mapView is tapped? A call to mapView.layer.removeAllAnimations() doesn't seem to do the trick and I'm unsure if I can safely simulate a touch event to send to the mapView.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These animations are directly managed by the map view, so they can’t be cancelled using Core Animation API.

Unfortunately there’s no public Mapbox method to cancel a camera movement, but there are a variety of ways to trigger a halt, such as by using a gesture or changing the camera again.

One hack (that I’m mildly ashamed to suggest) is to imperceptibly change the zoom level:

```
self.mapView.zoomLevel = self.mapView.zoomLevel + 0.01;
```

... this will immediately cancel any ongoing transitions.

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for your response. And funny timing, was about to return to this issue today to test if calling `setCamera()`  with the mapView.camera would trigger a halt. Curious to see if that works but either way, your suggestion is cleaner.

Really enjoying MapBox overall!